# How to get edited value from cxgrid lookupcombobox

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-7, tcxgrid

Delphi-7, DevExpress ExpressQuantumGrid Suite For Delphi.BCB v5.8 Fianl

I have a lookupcombobox column in cxGrid named **emaillist_id**. Where **emaillist_id** is KeyField and **Email** is ListField. A user can either choose an email from the list or type a new one. When user  type new **Email** I want to add it to a database table using SP. For that I need to get edited value. How can I do that?

Or maybe, there is a better solution for this problem.

```
procedure TfrmClientEmail.grdClientEMailDBTableViewEditValueChanged(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem);
begin
  if AItem.Index=(Sender as TcxGridDBTableView).GetColumnByFieldName('emaillist_id').Index then
   with ADOSP_ClientEmailEdit do
     begin
        Parameters.ParamValues['@KodClient']:=ADOSP_ClientEmail['KodClient'];
        Parameters.ParamValues['@email']:=Sender.Controller.EditingController.Edit.EditValue;//This return KeyFieldValue
        ExecProc();
     end;
     ADOSP_ClientEmailRefresh();
end;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the event `Properties.OnNewLookupDisplayText`. Here you get the EditValue (DisplayText) as parameter.